# Is there a directory equivalent of /dev/null in Linux?

Tags: linux, fhs

When configuring an application, you can often use `/dev/null` as config file if you want the application to read an empty file. But, if the application reads a list of files from a directory, you cannot use this trick. You would need to give it an empty directory to read.

I was wondering: does Linux have a default empty directory that can be used for such purposes? I know OpenSSH used /var/empty for a while, and I can of course create an empty dir myself, but maybe the FHS has specified a standard directory for this?

Comment: On my system, `/var/empty` is not empty, but contains a folder called `sshd`, so you probably don't want to use that.

Comment: If it's just for you you could always create `/var/empty`

Comment: Just a point: The special aspect of `/dev/null` isn't so much for *reading* as for *writing.*  Data written to `/dev/null` just disappears.  So, a directory equivalent would be a place where `mv yourfile /dev/empty` would result in deleting your file.

Comment: @Wildcard I presume you mean `mv yourfile /dev/empty/`. If you do `mv yourfile /dev/empty`, you're trying to replace the special directory.

Comment: @Wildcard The obvious caveat here is that when crossing file system boundaries `mv` will copy all the files first and then delete the originals. So that could turn into a very inefficient way to delete files.

Comment: @Wildcard while you're generally correct, it's worth noting (to avoid misconceptions) that piping `/dev/null` through `dd` is often used to initialize swapfiles.

Comment: @Rhymoid if a directory already exists, `mv` interprets a command such as `mv file /path/to/directory` as "move the file into the directory".

Comment: @Jules No, it isn't. You can't initialise anything with `/dev/null` and `dd` because `dd` will get an EOF before it's even written a single byte. I think you're thinking of `/dev/zero`, which is often used to fill something with or generate a specific number of zeros.

Comment: @MichealJohnson Good point. It kinda depends on how `mv` detects that, and whether it will know that a special directory is "special" or not.

Comment: @MichealJohnson you're right, my mistake, I'd confused `/dev/null` with `/dev/zero`.

Comment: @MichealJohnson If you need a file of a certain size you can create it using for example `dd if=/dev/null of=target seek=100 bs=1G` if the needed size is 100GB. It won't work for swap files though because the created file will be sparse and a swap file must not be sparse.

Comment: @Wildcard: (1) It’s important that `/dev/null` return an immediate EOF on input, because asynchronous (background) processes have their stdin redirected to `/dev/null`. This is better than just closing stdin (as in `<&-`) because (1a) that would cause `read()` to return an error rather than EOF, and (1b) it would allow the next `open()` to return 0. (2) `grep` didn’t always have the `-H` (`--with-filename`) option. Before that existed, `grep pattern /dev/null *` was the standard trick to get `grep` to report the filename even if `*` expanded to only one file.

Comment: @kasperd - won't running `mkswap` on the 100G file finish making it swap?

Comment: @warren All that `mkswap` does is to write a header to the file. It will still be sparse. Test this sequence of commands `dd if=/dev/null of=target seek=100 bs=1G`; `mkswap target`; `swapon target`. (You don't even need to be `root` to test that as it fails before you even reach the step that checks for root privileges.)

Comment: pathconf: not a directory.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) provides no "standard" empty directory.

It is common for Linux systems to provide a directory `/var/empty`, but this directory is not defined in FHS and may not actually be empty. Instead, certain daemons will create their own empty directories in here. For instance, openssh uses the empty directory `/var/empty/sshd` for privilege separation.

If your need for an empty directory is transient, you can create an empty directory yourself, as a subdirectory of `/run` or `/tmp`. If you're doing this outside the program, you can use [`mktemp -d`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) for this, or use the [`mkdtemp(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp) C function inside your program. Though if you *always* need the empty directory to be present, consider creating one under `/var/empty` as openssh does.

For this use case, creating a directory under `/tmp` is probably the best fit, though in practice it doesn't matter very much where you put it.

Comment: I would not recommend creating subdirectories under `/var/empty`, since any programs that use it (like OpenSSH in its [default config](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/fdfbf4580de09d84a974211715e14f88a5704b8e/pathnames.h#L157)) may expect it to be actually empty. (The `/var/empty/sshd` thing appears to be a weird RedHat-ism; Debian uses `/var/run/sshd` instead.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The bit of code you've linked doesn't support your assertion that OpenSSH expects `/var/empty` to be empty. Is there somewhere else one might look for this?

Comment: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/README.privsep maybe?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Hm, that document is out of date. It refers to `/var/empty` but the code actually uses `/var/empty/sshd`. Try again. :)

Comment: The link I gave points to the head of the `master` branch of the portable OpenSSH project on Github. It *should* be up to date; can *you* substantiate your claim that "the code actually uses `/var/empty/sshd`"? As far as I can tell, it does not, unless the default `/var/empty` path is altered by you or your distro (as RedHat, apparently, does). If it did, I'd expect the path `/var/empty/sshd` to actually be [mentioned outside the `contrib/redhat` folder](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/search?q=%22%2Fvar%2Fempty%2Fsshd%22&type=Code) in the code.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Hmm. Now I think you're right, after actually looking at the source which does the chroot() call. I find it amazing that there would be such an obviously stupid flaw in openssh, that Red Hat would have to maintain a downstream correction for.

Comment: I don't see how it's a "stupid flaw" -- having a guaranteed empty root-owned directory at a standard location, for use as a chroot jail, seems like a perfectly good idea to me. Of course, RedHat had to go and ruin it for everybody, by creating subdirectories under it. As a result, my recommendation for portable code would be not to use `/var/empty` for anything, since you can't be sure of its semantics on any given system. Creating your own empty directory e.g. under `/var/run`, like Debian does, seems more sensible.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen No, it's a terrible idea, especially for this purpose. You don't want multiple daemons chrooting to the same directory. They could then leak information among each other. Having a unique empty directory for every daemon closes this hole.

Comment: Not if it's owned by root and not writable, like `/var/empty` on *BSD is.

Answer (score 37):

You can use [`mktemp -d`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?mktemp++NetBSD-current) to create a new empty temporary directory with secure permissions, by default in `/tmp/`. The utility will output the new directory's path on `STDOUT`, so it is useful in the shell.

It's more portable than a systemd unit file anyway.

Comment: Yes, you could, but that's impractical if that directory has to be specified in a configuration file. You would want a permanent dir for that.

Answer (score 31):

[This Unix question](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/9332/17535) has some suggestions for creating a "blackhole" directory, including a [nullfs FUSE filesystem](https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs).

Comment: I do not know why the mktemp / mkdtemp answer is upvoted so heavily when this is the perfect answer. nullfs is the equivalent of /dev/null.

Answer (score 12):

For services systemd provides the option [`PrivateTmp`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=) to create private `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` directories that are not shared by processes outside of the namespace for that service and which should be empty (initially).

```
[Service]
ExecStart=...
PrivateTmp=yes
```

Comment: The program might create other temporary files, so you can't assume `/tmp` will be empty merely because it's been namespaced.